# How to apply custom css code introduced in textarea using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making sites that can be edited using CSS selectors.
But now I have to make an advanced section where the user can put their CSS code in a textarea to edit the styles manually
for example

```
.anyClass {
  text-align: center;
  color: blue;
}

#anyId {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

.anyDiv {
  text-align: center;
  color: yellow;
}

.spacer-line border-primary{
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
  border-color: blue;
}
```

**these IDs and classes are only examples, the script must accept whatever data is entered, for example .columns-mobile, .custom-button, etc**

If I have the entered data as string in javascript, how can I add this to the page for update the css style?

The best way would be to insert all the code to the header of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you added `id="textar"` to the textarea

```
var textArea = document.getElementById("textar");

//To add classes:
textArea.classList.add("className");

//To remove classes:
textArea.classList.remove("className");
```

Where, `classname` is the class which you dynamically need to add.

If you want to add or remove classes as the user types in the textarea, you can do:

```
textArea.addEventListener('change', () => {
    //If you want to add
    textArea.classList.add(textArea.value);

    //Similarly for remove
});
```

Comment: But I need to apply the site css code introduced by the user via javascript, I have the value as string, textarea is simply the input component

Comment: `textArea.classList.add(string)` where string is the string you have as the value

Comment: If you want to add to some other element then, `otherelement.classList ...`. I just took textArea as an example. It applies for **all DOM Elements**

Comment: I don't want to edit the textarea, the textarea is the input component of the code. I want to add CSS code to the main HTML site

Comment: That is what I am saying

Comment: Ok, thanks, I have to add the styles by   document.head.appendChild(style);?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232256/discussion-between-atheesh-thirumalairajan-and-andre-cuellar-avaroma).